# Modern OpenGL Example from github

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, g++, glfw

I found this example code on github via https://github.com/zuck/opengl-examples.git this is the mirroed cube example

I can get this code to work if I use cmake to build it,
what I want to do is to be able to compile and link through g++

I have used several variations of the following command

```
g++ *.cpp -o main -lGLEW -lGL -lglfw -lX11 -lXrandr -lXxf86vm -lXi -lpthread -lrt -lm
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define GLEW_STATIC

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>



#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <stb/stb_image.h>

#define GLM_FORCE_RADIANS
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

#define GLSL(src) "#version 150 core\n" #src

int main()
{
    // -------------------------------- INIT ------------------------------- //

    // Init GLFW
    if (glfwInit() != GL_TRUE) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Create a rendering window with OpenGL 3.2 context
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "OpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Init GLEW
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Initialize OpenGL
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);

    // ----------------------------- RESOURCES ----------------------------- //

    // Create Vertex Array Object
    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    // Create a Vertex Buffer Object and copy the vertex data to it
    GLuint vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,

        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,

        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,

         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,

        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

        -1.5f, -1.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
         1.5f, -1.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
         1.5f,  1.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.5f,  1.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.5f,  1.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.5f, -1.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f
    };

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Create and compile the vertex shader
    const char* vertexSource = GLSL(
        uniform mat4 trans;
        uniform mat4 view;
        uniform mat4 proj;
        uniform vec3 overrideColor;

        in vec3 position;
        in vec3 color;
        in vec2 texcoord;

        out vec3 Color;
        out vec2 Texcoord;

        void main() {
            Color = overrideColor * color;
            Texcoord = texcoord;
            gl_Position = proj * view * trans * vec4(position, 1.0);
        }
    );

    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    // Create and compile the fragment shader
    const char* fragmentSource = GLSL(
        uniform sampler2D tex0;
        uniform sampler2D tex1;

        in vec3 Color;
        in vec2 Texcoord;

        out vec4 outColor;

        void main() {
            outColor = mix(texture(tex0, Texcoord), texture(tex1, Texcoord), 0.5) * vec4(Color, 1.0);
        }
    );

    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    // Link the vertex and fragment shader into a shader program
    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glBindFragDataLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "outColor");
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

    // Create 2 textures and load images to them
    GLuint textures[2];
    glGenTextures(2, textures);

    int width, height, comp = 0;
    unsigned char* img = 0;

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
    img = stbi_load("Content/sample.png", &width, &height, &comp, 0);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "tex0"), 0);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    stbi_image_free(img);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[1]);
    img = stbi_load("Content/sample2.png", &width, &height, &comp, 0);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "tex1"), 1);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    stbi_image_free(img);

    // Transform matrices
    GLint uniTrans = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "trans");

    glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(
        glm::vec3(2.5f, 2.5f, 1.5f),
        glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
        glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)
    );
    GLint uniView = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "view");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniView, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));

    glm::mat4 proj = glm::perspective(45.0f, 800.0f / 600.0f, 1.0f, 10.0f);
    GLint uniProj = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "proj");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniProj, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(proj));

    // Specify the layout of the vertex data
    GLint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
    glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);

    GLint colAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "color");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(colAttrib);
    glVertexAttribPointer(colAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));

    GLint texAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "texcoord");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(texAttrib);
    glVertexAttribPointer(texAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)(6 * sizeof(GLfloat)));

    GLint uniColor = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "overrideColor");

    // ---------------------------- RENDERING ------------------------------ //

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // Clear the screen to black
        glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Apply a rotation
        glm::mat4 trans;
        trans = glm::rotate(
            trans,
            (float)sin(glfwGetTime()) * 2.0f,
            glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)
        );

        // Draw cube
        glUniform3f(uniColor, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(uniTrans, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(trans));
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

        glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
            // Draw floor
            glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 1, 0xFF);
            glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_REPLACE);
            glStencilMask(0xFF);
            glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
            glClear(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, 6);

            // Draw cube reflection
            glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 1, 0xFF);
            glStencilMask(0x00);
            glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);

            trans = glm::scale(glm::translate(trans, glm::vec3(0, 0, -1)), glm::vec3(1, 1, -1));
            glUniformMatrix4fv(uniTrans, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(trans));

            glUniform3f(uniColor, 0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f);
                glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
            glUniform3f(uniColor, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

        glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);

        // Swap buffers and poll window events
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    // ---------------------------- CLEARING ------------------------------ //

    // Delete allocated resources
    glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteTextures(2, textures);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);

    // ---------------------------- TERMINATE ----------------------------- //

    // Terminate GLFW
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

when ever I compile through cmake it works just fine. however if I compile through g++ I only get a blank white window that somtimes looks like it wants to work with flashing black lights but does not work as smoothly as it does with the cmake. The reason I want to use g++ is because I manually build and compile and link everything I do to help myself understand what exactly is happening through compilation.

Comment: "The reason I want to use g++ is because I manually build and compile and link everything I do to help myself understand what exactly is happening through compilation." - Start your learning with building CMake project via `make VERBOSE=1` and look into **exact command lines** used for compile and link it.

Comment: looks like I did everything the verbose output and I still got the same result, I think it has to do with glfw

Comment: In that case we can hardly help you.